# itemview in Adapter for recyclerview not getting id from xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, cardview

this is my class
i've been tryinng to get the imageviewcard which is an xml id un the cardview, and no matter if i do it with findviewbyid or just itemview. it is not catching it, i'm so desperate!!!

```
class CustomAdapter (


    private val list: List<DataCard>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
     val items: MutableList<CardView>
            init{
                this.items = ArrayList()
            }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.cardviews,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item: DataCard = list[position]

        holder.bind(item)
       // holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ettitle)
       // holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.cardimage)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return list.size }

    inner class ViewHolder
    internal constructor(
        itemView: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

         //  val ettitlecard: TextView = itemView.imageviewcard
       // val card: LinearLayout?= itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview)

        fun bind(item: DataCard) {
            
//THIS JUST WON'T WORK NOR WITH FINVIEWBYID
         //   val ettitlecard: TextView = itemView.ettitlecard
         //   val card: LinearLayout?= itemView.card

        }

        val binding = CardviewsBinding.bind(itemView)


    }
}
```

Comment: Share `cardviews.xml` layout code.

Answer (score 0):

could you share your layout.xml and the error you are getting to analyse your problem.

I think you can simplify your `ViewHolder` creation:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = CardviewsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

class ViewHolder(private val binding: CardviewsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        fun bind(item: DataCard) {
            // use binding here to populate view
        }
    }
```

Maybe this also fixes your problem.